# How do I add a condition to a standard model search?

Tags: php, laravel, graphql, lighthouse

My `graphql.schema` describes search queries (pagination, search by ID, etc.), but in addition to that I need to check some more conditions, for example, in my database there is a field containing information about whether a record has been deleted or not, i.e. I am not actually deleting the records, but just overwriting the value of that field.

Accordingly, now I get all the records, regardless of what the `exist` field is equal to.

I only need to get records where this field is equal to `true`.

I spent a lot of time looking for an answer in CO and reading the documentation, but I never found what I needed. The examples I've found assume the condition will be set on the client side, but I need to do this on the **backend** side.

Using *laravel* I can get an equivalent result with this code, so a solution might be a way to overwrite something that uses *lighthouse*:

```php
$product = Product::where('id', '=', $id)
                ->where('exist', '=', true)
                ->first();
```

Maybe I’m doing something wrong or I don’t understand something, but it looks like no one had such a need or problem.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

**`graphql.schema`**:

```graphql
type Query {
    products: [Product!]! @paginate
    product(id: ID @eq): Product @find
}

type Product {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    description: String!
    tags: [Tag!]! @belongsToMany(relation: "tags")
    view: File! @belongsTo(relation: "view")
    price: Float!
    discount: Float!
    quantity: Int!
    created_at: DateTime!
    updated_at: DateTime!
    exist: Boolean!
}
```

**`Product.php`**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Components\Product;

use App\Components\Tag\Tag;
use App\Components\File\File;
use App\Core\Model\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'description', 'tags', 'view_id', 'price', 'discount', 'quantity', 'exist'
    ];

    /**
     * @return BelongsToMany
     */
    public function tags(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return BelongsTo
     */
    public function view(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(File::class);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

---

**UPD 1:**

In addition, I need to find relations in the same way. I suspect it might not be *lighthouse* related and is solved by adding `middleware`.

**UPD 2:**

I know what I can create a resolver using the [`@field`](https://lighthouse-php.com/master/api-reference/directives.html#field) directive for all queries, but this solution won't work for relations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution! Apparently initially I missed this point in the documentation and began to write my own implementation

Now I switched to using [`SoftDeletes`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#soft-deleting) and everything worked as I needed :)